# Getting Google+ access token for basic information

Tags: windows-phone-7, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I am using code from [this tutorial](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Google+_authentication_in_Windows_Phone_application). I just modified it that I just get access token. It's working fine but I want to extended this by scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
```

And with this I have problem. Google is asking in webbrowser for more permissions but when I say ok I get exception in my `GetResponseCallback`:

```
The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

I found that this could be wrong and that developer should made emulator go throught proxy like in fiddler and then look at really error code. I found there that I have 400 Bad Request but how it could be that without that scope it's okay and with it it's bad request? Thanks for help

Edit:

[My code in pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/PFhH7FXd)

Comment: Can you show us the exact code you're using, including with the new scopes?

Comment: I added my code to pastebin. I hope it helps but as I said It's mainly same as code in tutorial.

Comment: One issue that won't cause the error is that you should not request plus.login, plus.me and userinfo.profile together. You should ONLY request plus.login as it encompasses those other two scopes.

Comment: Ok, I removed it but as you said It didn't cause the error.

Comment: You have multiple requests happening. Do you know which request is the cause? Is the authorization dialog displaying? Is the error happening after approval when you are attempting to post the code to get your access token?

Comment: Yes, authorization dialog is displaying and the error happens after I clicked allow (or submit, or something like that, I have google in other language than english) when I should get access token. I have two requests. For first which has informations there is response 302 Moved Temporarily. In the response there is new location with parameters and in second request I use that info and there is where I get response 400 Bad request.

Answer (score 3):

try to use this url as this is google profile

```
var url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=" + RedirctedUri
                      + "&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&client_id="
                      + ClientId;
```

is working for me.

and other issue can be when registering application you have not granted access for required data